# Using DataContractSurrogate with DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior WCF 4.5 preview .NET Standard

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

I am trying to migrate some WCF code to target .NET Standard 2.0 and am using System.ServiceModel.Primitives version 4.5.0-preview1. The DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior no longer exposes a DataContractSurrogate property. I know a surrogate can be used with a DataContractSerializer via the DataContractSerializerExtension, however I don’t see a way to utilize it with DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.

```
    public class MyDataContractSurrogate : ISerializationSurrogateProvider
    {
        ....
    }

    DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
    ser.SetSerializationSurrogateProvider(new MyDataContractSurrogate());
```

Is there a way to use a DataContractSurrogate in this version of WCF?

I have tried replacing the default DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior operation behavior by inheriting from DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior and returning a DataContractSerializer with an attached surrogate from the CreateSerializer method without any luck.